# How to add 'django.contrib.auth' app in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, pycharm

I deployed Django project using cloud code from pycharm.

but in this sample template, there were not the code in installed_app basic apps like these

> 'django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

there was only 'django.contrib.staticfiles' apps.

Also the default middleweres were not completely installed

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'helloapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

So, is there any way to use default apps to make login page.?

Comment: Why not add those apps?

Comment: Can't you add them manually? This is why I prefer not to choose automation of deploying and so on. This question so far belongs more to Jetbrains team rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: I haven't found any way to add it manually in web. Anyone knows the way?